# Conditionally render different stack navigators in tab navigator based on redux state

Tags: react-native

My App has a bottom tab navigator, where one of the tabs (Rep) needs to render a different stack Navigator based on redux state. The state is set by running a query after successful authentication and navigating to the default screen (MyPathScreen).

I tried to implement the following approach:

```
const isRep = useSelector(selectIsRep);
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="My Path"
      })}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Rep"
        component={
          isRep ? RepNavigator : RepApplicationNavigator
        }
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Rep',
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="My Path"
        component={PathNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'My Path',
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="My Account"
        component={MyAccountNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'My Account',
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

However, on every login and logout I get the following error:
Warning: Cannot update a component (`TabNavigator`) while rendering a different component (`MyPathScreen`). What am I doing wrong? How do I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I solved this issue with wrapping my dispatch in useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that

The condition should wrap whole tab.screen

```js
isRep ? (<Tab.Screen
        name="Rep"
        component={
          RepNavigator 
        }
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Rep',
        }}
      />)
:

(<Tab.Screen
        name="RepApp"
        component={
          RepApplicationNavigator 
        }
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Rep',
        }}
      />)
```

More info with authentication flow with react navigation:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

Comment: This gives me exactly the same error that I am trying to fix. "Cannot update a component while rendering a different component"

Comment: Change name of the tab screen

Comment: Unfortunately, the error is still there. I'm afraid my only option is to run the query in the TabNavigator itself

Comment: Is RepApplicationNavigator a screen?